# get count of "yes" from my multiple objects of List<string>

Tags: c#

I want to get count of '*yes*' from my multiple objects of List(string). lets suppose I have three list `sig1`, `sig2` and `sig3` and they all contain either '*yes*' or '*no*'. and I want to get the count of '*yes*' from `sig1` where `sig2` is '*yes*' and `sig3` is '*no*'.

Comment: what is the structure of sid1, sig2 and sig3? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You are going to need to clarify this, its very hard to follow

Comment: What do you mean by where sig2 is 'yes' and sig3 is 'no'?

Comment: List<String> sig1 = new List<string>(); List<String> sig2 = new List<string>(); List<String> sig3 = new List<string>(); here are the three list objects and they contain thousands of 'yes' and 'no' only... what i want that the count of sig1 where it is 'yes' and sig2 is 'yes' and sig3 is 'no'. means at position 0 if sig1 is 'yes' and sig2 is 'yes' and sig3 is 'no'. than it should return the count 1.

Comment: Why not just use bool lists instead?

Answer (score 3):

What i got from your question is that you probably 3 lists of strings having equal number of items and you want to know the count of the `yes` where `sign1` and `sign2` is `yes` and `sign3` is `no`.

```
List<string> sign1, sign2, sign3;
int count = sign1.Where((item, index) => (sign1[index] == 'yes') &&
                                         (sign2[index] == 'yes') && 
                                         (sign3[index] == 'no')).Count();
```

Comment: thnx fr d help , yp thats what i want.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really hard to understand but I'm guessing something like this is what you want.

```
List<string> myAnswers = new List<string>() { "yes", "yes", "no" };
Int32 numberOfPositiveAnswers = myAnswers.Count(x => x.Equals("yes"));
```

The value of `numberOfPositiveAnswers` would then be 2.

Comment: List<String> sig1 = new List<string>();
List<String> sig2 = new List<string>();
List<String> sig3 = new List<string>();

here are the three list objects and they contain thousands of 'yes' and 'no' only... what i want that the count of sig1 where it is 'yes' and sig2 is 'yes' and sig3 is 'no'.

means at position 0 if sig1 is 'yes' and sig2 is 'yes' and sig3 is 'no'. than it should return the count 1.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly you want to get a count of "yes" from list 1 when the items at the same index in list 2 is "yes" and the same index of list 3 is no.

```
    List<string> sig1 = new List<string>(new string[]{"yes","yes","yes"});
    List<string> sig2 = new List<string>(new string[] { "yes", "no", "yes" });
    List<string> sig3 = new List<string>(new string[] { "no", "yes", "no" });

    int count = sig1.Where((s, index) => s == "yes"
             && sig2.ElementAtOrDefault(index) == "yes" 
             && sig3.ElementAtOrDefault(index) == "no").Count();
```

Comment: thnx for the help... yes thats what i want.. :)